# Matplotlib - Plot uneven steps from DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have this `DataFrame` with x-axis data organized in column. However, for the non-existent, the columns were omitted, so the steps are uneven. For instance:

```
   0.1  0.2  0.5 ...
0    1    4    7 ...
1    2    5    8 ... 
2    3    6    9 ...
```

I want to plot each of those in with x-axis `np.arange(0, max(df.columns), step=0.1)` and also combined plot of those. Is there any easy way to achieve this with `matplotlib.pyplot`?

```py
plt.plot(np.arange(0, max(df.columns), step=0.1), new_data)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of plot do you need?

Comment: @steven line graph

Comment: Could you be more specific? You have a column of data for every step. There must be some grouping right? Like having a line for each row?

Comment: @steven Yes, a line for each row

Comment: Since you want your column headers as x-axis and your rows as individual lines, perhaps you meant to plot your data like `plt.plot(df.T)`, i.e. "rotated" by 90 degrees?

Comment: @Asmus my question is I want to ‘impute’ the missing headers and fill it with 0 in the plot, if that makes sense. Similar to doing np.arange mentioned in the question. So I want to have 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, ... in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your final dataframe is supposed to look like this:

```
   0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5
0  0.0    1    4  0.0  0.0    7
1  0.0    2    5  0.0  0.0    8
2  0.0    3    6  0.0  0.0    9
```

which can be generated (and then also plotted) like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0.1:[1,2,3],0.2:[4,5,6],0.5:[7,8,9]})

## make sure to actually include the maximum value (add one step)
#  or alternatively rather use np.linspace() with appropriate number of points
xs = np.arange(0, max(df.columns) +0.1, step=0.1)

df = df.reindex(columns=xs, fill_value=0.0)

plt.plot(df.T)
plt.show()
```

which yields:

[image: simple line plot of the dataframe]